# Testing SharePoint List Workflow from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a custom workflow in Visual Studio 2010 for SharePoint 2010 and have run into a problem. I have figured out how to deploy the workflow to the SharePoint site, but executing it results in an error. However, the error message is completely non-descriptive, so I want to find out if there is a way to execute it from Visual Studio so I can see where it fails, and possibly why.

I'm trying to simply create a new subsite based on a given `ListItem.Title` information.

How is it you go about debugging?

For reference, here is my code

```
class CreateSubsite : System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity
{
    protected override System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutionStatus
        Execute(System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
    {
        createSite();
        return System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed;
    }

    public void createSite()
    {
        using (SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {
            using (SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web)
            {
                SPList currentList = SPContext.Current.List;
                SPListItem currentListItem = SPContext.Current.ListItem;

                WorkflowContext workflow = new WorkflowContext();
                SPSite parentSite = new SPSite(workflow.CurrentWebUrl);

                SPWeb newSite = currentSite.AllWebs.Add(
                    currentListItem.Title.Replace(" ", "_"),
                    currentListItem.Title,
                    String.Empty, currentWeb.Language, "CI Template", false, false
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove Using keyword from your code .You should not dispose your SPSite and SPWeb when you use *SPContext* because disposing of that object might actually break the workflow as it may still need a reference to that object for later use.
just rewrite your code without use using

```
  public void createSite() {
        SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site 
        SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web
         //.... Rest of your code
```

Hope that help
Regards.

Comment: Thanks! I discovered Intellitrace so that is what I am currently working on understanding and putting to use.

Comment: If someone stumbles upon this, I ended up deploying the Workflow, enabling it on my site, running the workflow, then searching the Log files located in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS"

I also discovered that you cannot use SPContext within a Workflow (it returns null and causes the Workflow to error) 
source: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.aspx)